# OutOfMemoryError using BitmapDrawables

Tags: android

I download and keep a list of photos in my application:

```
List<BitmapDrawable> photos = new ArrayList<BitmapDrawable>();
photos.add(Utils.bitmapToBitmapDrawable(downloadBitmap(s));

public static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    // GET input stream from server
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
}
```

Trying to deallocate:

```
if (dldedPics.get(0).getPhotos() != null && !dldedPics.get(0).getPhotos().isEmpty()) {
    for (BitmapDrawable b : dldedPics.get(0).getPhotos()) {
        b.getBitmap().recycle();
    }
}
dldedPics.get(0).setPhotos(null);
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

I can't seem to properly have them deallocated, as I get a OutOfMemoryError (at the decodeStream line) rather quickly, after 10-20 100kb photos.

Stacktrace:

```
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:459)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:515)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at com.domain.persistence.Utils.downloadBitmap(Utils.java:385)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at com.domain.service.tasks.AllPhotosDownloaderTask.doInBackground(AllPhotosDownloaderTask.java:51)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at com.domain.service.tasks.AllPhotosDownloaderTask.doInBackground(AllPhotosDownloaderTask.java:1)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-23 09:43:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(3079):     ... 4 more
11-23 09:43:08.201: E/dalvikvm-heap(3079): 240000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
11-23 09:43:08.231: E/GraphicsJNI(3079): VM won't let us allocate 240000 bytes
```

Comment: try after making `BitmapDrawable b`  as `WeakReference`

Comment: WeakReference<BitmapDrawable> bref = that way also see Google Shelves Application

Comment: I've found no WeakReference or Bitmap.recycle() usages in the Shelves application.

Comment: Also, I've posted the exception log.

Comment: Your virtual machine doesnt have the memory budget, to allocate 240KB of data. You need to increase the VM memory allowance, or decrease the amount you read in

Comment: I know that, please look at my actual question.

Answer (score 0):

You should only load the image size you need, not the entire image.

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = scale;
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

*If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels.*

Comment: This is certainly not the issue, as I do need the whole image (100kb in size?), and nothing happens for a set of images. The issue I have is that multiple set of images are still being kept in the memory even though they aren't referenced anymore.

Comment: Your say the image is 100kb. Is this a bitmap or a compressed format like JPG or PNG? A bitmap will be significantly bigger than a PNG/JPG. It is also good practice to only load the image in the size you need it for.

Comment: My JPG image is 100kb. A Bitmap object is probably 4 times that. However, I do need its full size. Again, nothing would go wrong as long as I could deallocate it once I'm done with a set.